# Inconsistent behavior when coercing an Array to a List?

Tags: arrays, list, raku, coerce

```
my @foo; 
@foo = (1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6), 7), (8), 9).List;
say @foo.flat;
# OUTPUT: (1 (2 3) (4 (5 6) 7) 8 9)
# this is NOT the output I expected.

@foo = (1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6), 7), (8), 9);
say @foo.List.flat;
# OUTPUT: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
# this is the output I expected.

say $*DISTRO; # macos (12.6)
say $*VM;     # moar (2022.07)
say $*RAKU;   # Raku (6.d)
say $*KERNEL; # darwin
```

It seems that coercing in the assignment has no effect.

Why does it matter when @foo is coerced to a List?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [the @ sigil](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#The_@_sigil), documentation states

> By default, when you assign a `List` to an @-sigiled variable, you create an `Array`.

"assign" there refers to `=`, and RHS need not be List actually; after `my @f = ...`, `@f` ends up of the type Array. (In your case RHS happens to be a List; in fact, it's a List already with the literal so you don't need `.List` there).

Now, since `@foo` is an Array, it puts its elements in [scalar](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar) [containers](https://docs.raku.org/language/containers), which [resist](https://docs.raku.org/routine/flat#(Iterable)_method_flat) against flattening, hence the behaviour you see.

```raku
>>> my @foo = (1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6), 7), (8), 9)
[1 (2 3) (4 (5 6) 7) 8 9]

>>> @foo.WHAT
(Array)

>>> @foo.flat
(1 (2 3) (4 (5 6) 7) 8 9)
```

As mentioned in the first link, you can get `@foo` as a List if you do `my @foo := ...` instead, i.e., via binding, or overriding the default type on Positionals explicitly, i.e., `my @foo is List = ...` (or by changing the sigil, e.g., `my $foo := ...`...).

As for the second case, `@foo.List` makes a new List object out of `@foo`; so no scalar container, yes full flattening:

```raku
>>> @foo.List
(1 (2 3) (4 (5 6) 7) 8 9)

>>> @foo.List.WHAT
(List)

>>> @foo.List.flat
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: Thank you, Mustafa!  That is a very clear answer.